# Wordpress plugin: admin-ajax.php not passing data to custom function

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

n this basic plugin skeleton, I am trying to get the data sent by ajax to wordpress admin-ajax.php to be processed by a custom function.

It looks like the data send from the form does not reach my ea_ajax_handler() function.
It seems to arrive to admin-ajax.php (the form data is collected by jQuery, then I get a 200 response for the post request to admin-ajax.php), but it looks like it not forwarded to ea_ajax_handler().

Here are my files:

easyA.php:

```
/** Enqueue scripts */
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ea_scripts');

function ea_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // easyA script in the footer
    wp_register_script('easyA', plugins_url('js/easyA.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easyA'); // wondering if it's really needed or if the previous line is enough...
    wp_localize_script('easyA', 'easyAVars', array('ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

/** Shortcode to display form in pages / posts */
add_shortcode('easyA','ea_display_form');

function ea_display_form()
{
    echo '
        <form id="eaForm">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        ';
}

/** Event handling */
add_action('wp_ajax_ea_ajax_handler', 'ea_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ea_ajax_handler', 'ea_ajax_handler');

function ea_ajax_handler() 
{
    $json = array(
        'success' => false,
        'result'  => 0
    );

    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $result = 'Hi, ' . $_POST['username'] . '!';

        $json['success'] = true;
        $json['result'] = $result;
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
    wp_die();
}
```

easyA.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#eaForm').on('submit', function() {
        var that = $(this),
            contents = that.serialize();

        console.log('contents: ' + contents); // debugging
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: easyAVars.ajaxUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: contents,
            action: 'ea_ajax_handler', // function in easyA.php that will be triggered
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The action should be added to contents. so after setting contents and before the ajax call, add a line that says contents.action = 'ea_ajax_handler'

Comment: @czerspalace Thank you but adding `contents.action = 'ea_ajax_handler';` right after `contents = that.serialize();` didn't work.

Comment: `that.serialize()` doesn't create a jQuery object, it creates a string with form: `username=Smith`. So to add the action you'd need to concatenate the string. `contents = that.serialize + '&action=ea_ajax_handler` (untested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As czerspalace mentioned you need to pass the action to the `.ajax()`.

One way to do this would be to modify your form:

```
function ea_display_form()
{
    echo '
        <form id="eaForm">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ea_ajax_handler" />
        </form>
        ';
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Actually, I also removed `action: 'ea_ajax_handler',` in the ajax() which seemed not to be needed (still working without it).

Comment: Great! If you review the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) you'll see that `action` is only passed inside the `data` object... by itself it is meaningless to the `.ajax()` function.

Comment: Thank you for this (sorry can't +1 your comment, not enough rep yet)!